# Lista de chapéus secretos Winter/Summer Bash 2022 ☃️ ️

Tags: debate

Na a data de hoje (17/12) somos a **segunda comunidade** com mais chapéus do Winter/Summer Bash 2022 (o 1º item é a soma geral, e mais que nós, só o Stack Overflow em Inglês): https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/leaderboard

[image: winterbash 2022 liderança]

Parabéns para todos nós :)

Estou postando aqui a lista de chapéus secretos e como obtê-los, adaptando da postagem:

- [Winter / Summer Bash 2022 Hat List ☃️ ️](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384709/198279)

A lista de chapéus regulares pode ser encontrada no site: https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Chápeus secretos Winter/Summer Bash 2022

> **Edite esta postagem com um gatilho de chapéu secreto somente se tiver sido verificado pela equipe, vinculando à verificação**

---

#### Over 9000!

[image]

> Crie uma questão que pontue 2 ou mais com a tag `discussion` em qualquer site META da rede (no Stack Overflow em Português use a tag [debate](/questions/tagged/debate)) - Nota: deve pontuar oito ou mais no MSO ou MSE - [confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62609318).

---

#### Collection Complete

[image]

**Note:** O design deste chapéu foi modificado durante o winterbash, para mais [detalhes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384765/this-years-winter-bash-violates-the-geneva-conventions-no-really).

> Outro usuário salvou uma de suas postagens ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62575431#62575431))

---

#### Not Found

[image]

> Visite a página /404 de um site SE (exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/404) ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62573482#62573482))

---

#### Heads up!

[image]

> Faça uma sinalização que seja considerada como útil ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62571008#62571008))

---

#### Back In My Day

[image]

> Vote a favor de uma pergunta com mais de 5 anos ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62581699#62581699))

---

#### X Marks the Spot

[image]

> Obtenha três outros chapéus secretos em um site ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62570982#62570982))

---

#### Chatterbox

[image]

> Envie 5 blocos distintos de mensagens, em uma sala, em 1 dia ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62585082#62585082))

---

#### Flagging

[image]

> 9 sinalizações marcadas como úteis em suas 10 sinalizações mais recentes em perguntas distintas ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62620616#62620616))

---

#### Unflagging

[image]

> 23 sinalizações marcadas como úteis em suas 25 sinalizações mais recentes em perguntas distintas([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62620616#62620616))

---

#### Everything Everywhere All At Once

[image]

> Dê 10 votos positivos em respostas de uma mesma pergunta ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62589964#62589964))

---

#### Emperor's New Hat

[image]

---

#### This Is The Way

[image]

> Fazer uma pergunta que recebe um voto positivo, não é fechada e recebe uma resposta
> ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62602657#62602657))

---

#### Thomas Mensah

[image]

---

#### Albert Einstein

[image]

---

#### Verified

[image]

> Publique 8 mensagens de chat com uma estrela ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62586004#62586004))

---

#### I'm Okay...

[image]

> Responda a uma pergunta de recompensa, mas não receba a recompensa e tenha uma pontuação positiva ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62577795#62577795))

---

#### Mario Molina

[image]

> Complete 3 revisões de reabertura, onde a maioria dos eleitores concordaram com você. Revisões sem votos não contam! (Nota: é necessário 10 revosões no Stack Overflow em Inglês) (confirmado por Catija)

---

#### Running Up That Hill

[image]

---

#### Defender of the Unicorn

[image]

> Publique uma pergunta com uma tag [winter-bash](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winter-bash) que mais tarde receberá uma tag [status-completed](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) no Meta Stack Exchange ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62584186#62584186))
>  
>  *(Chapéu e gatilho inalterados desde 2021)*

#### Four Ayes

[image]

> Receber voto positivo em uma postagem, pelo menos um por dia, durante quatro dias, sem receber negativos durante o período  ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62599271#62599271))

---

#### Shakuntala Devi

[image]

> Revise pelo menos uma postagem da Primeira pergunta por dia durante 5 dias. Os dias não precisam ser consecutivos ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62629314#62629314))

---

#### Hedy Lamarr

[image]

> Revise pelo menos uma postagem de primeira resposta por dia durante 5 dias. Os dias não precisam ser consecutivos ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62629294#62629294))

---

#### Gregorio Y. Zara

[image]

> Revise pelo menos uma postagem de baixa qualidade por dia durante 5 dias. Os dias não precisam ser consecutivos ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62629212#62629212))

---

#### Solstice (Sun) / Solstice (Moon)

[image]

[image]

> Participar/fazer qualquer ação no solstício de verão - ou inverno, no hemisfério norte - (21 de dezembro de 2022) ([confirmado por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62617091#62617091))
>  
>  *(Este chapéu tem duas formas, mas você só pode obter uma)*

---

#### Yes, a Robot

[image]

> [Visite Sparkles a Unicórnio (`/visit-sparkles`)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385137/lets-check-in-on-sparkles-the-unicorn) mas falhe em guiá-la de volta para casa ([hat award page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GOwP.png))

---

#### Introverts Unite

[image]

> Realize qualquer ação no Dia Internacional do Introvertido (2 de Janeiro de 2023) ([confirmedo por Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62679488))